# Bash code for merging 3 files in specific order

Tags: linux, bash, dataframe, awk, sed

I am using samtools (Seq tool) and it generated tab file.

(A) I will be in the end getting two tab file :- 
File A contains only 1 value 100000
File B contains only 1 value 110000 
File C contains two names in column 1 : 
e.g.
name A
name B
File D (output file) which is a merge of all 3 files in this order

Column1    Column2
gene A     100000
gene B     110000

Many thanks in advance guys..

regards 
Gaurav

Comment: You can do a better description - please post actual examples for all files and how do you want the end result to look like. Also specify all delimiters between the columns in all files. This should be solvable with cut, paste and awk

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting help.. and add what you've tried (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @hovanessyan. Thanks for the reply. As per your suggestion, I have updated the question in a more simplified manner. Also I know it can be achieved by cut and copy method but this script is a small part of a big bash script. I wanted to make it automated the whole process, therefore your input will be appreciated. many thanks

Comment: cut, paste and awk are all bash commands and can be used in bash scripts to automate a process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`awk`** + **`paste`** solution:

Sample files:

```
$ head f[123]
==> f1 <==
gene A
gene B

==> f2 <==
100
200
300
400

==> f3 <==
1000
2000
3000
4000
```

---

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{ a[NR]=$0; next }{ $0=(a[FNR%2==0? 2:1] OFS)$0 }1' f1 <(paste f2 f3)
```

The output:

```
gene A  100 1000
gene B  200 2000
gene A  300 3000
gene B  400 4000
```